# Is it possible in Qt to catch the event of an extra monitor being connected or disconnected?

Tags: qt, events

When I use my laptop at home there is an extra monitor connected to it. However sometimes I disconnect the second display (D2) temporarily (for instance because I need the ThunderBolt connection on my Mac). Usually the OS takes care of moving  all the visible windows that were visible on D2 to the first display (D1). However if the resolution of D1 is much higher than D0 windows are shrunk just enough the fill the whole screen of D0. This is ugly and inconvenient for the user.

So my question: is it possible to write an event handler or event filter for the occurrence of the event of connecting or disconnecting a second monitor? There might be other uses than the one I described above. Perhaps it is impossible because the OS does not tell any application that the windows were moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QDesktopWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html) provides the signal [`screenCountChanged(int)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html#screenCount-prop). One thing to note is that if screen mirroring is enabled, the screen count will be 1, but if the second screen is detached the `screenCountChanged(..)` signal is *not* emitted but the main screen may resize, so you may want to also checkout [`QDesktopWidget::resized(int)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html#resized).